# Having two Windows excluded in a IfWinNotActive in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I am mapping Alt+F4 to ESC so that I can close windows just by pressing escape. However there are two windows that I need to actually use ESC in. So, when either of these two windows are active I want to be able to press ESC without closing the window. What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I have my script working when I just am excluding one active window but I need to work when either of the two windows are active.

Here is my attempted code:

```
GroupAdd, ESC, Untitled - Notepad
GroupAdd, ESC, 

#IfWinNotActive, ahk_group, ESC
Escape::!F4
Return
```

This is the code that works properly with just one window:

```
;#IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad
;Escape::!F4
;Return
```

**UPDATE:** Should this work?

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad
#IfWinNotActive, Document 1 - Microsoft Word
    Escape::!F4
Return
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your `#IfWinNotActive` line after `ahk_group`

Try the following:

```
GroupAdd, ESC, Untitled - Notepad
;  Add more windows to the group if necessary

#IfWinNotActive, ahk_group ESC
    Escape::!F4
Return
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `SetTitleMatchMode`.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm

> 2: A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a
>   match.

Then you can do this (it is case-sensitive by default):

```
settitlematchmode, 2
#IfWinNotActive, Untitled -
```

Try this:

First, you can't remap the same key twice in the same script.

> This command affects the behavior of all windowing commands, e.g.
>   IfWinExist and WinActivate.

Second, you stack lines like this:

```
#IfWinNotActive, Untitled - Notepad
#IfWinNotActive, Document 1 - Microsoft Word
```

you are saying, if win1 is not active, THEN if win2 is not active.

Try this, instead:

```
settitlematchmode, 2
app1 := winexist("other app")
app2 := winexist("Untitled - Notepad")

if(app1 || app2)    ;the || means OR.  you can use && for AND.
    Escape::!F4   ;you can only map a particular key one time per script
```

or this, which is more along the lines of your approach:

```
settitlematchmode, 2
GroupAdd, ESC, Untitled - Notepad
GroupAdd, ESC, My other window
IfWinNotActive, ahk_group ESC
    Escape::!F4
Return
```

Comment: So if the two windows I want excluded have completely different titles it should look like this, correct? See change above.

Comment: This seems to overcomplicate it. He should be able to add the `SetTitleMatchMode 2` and simply add more windows to the group.

Comment: Thanks for both of your guys help on this. It seems that that something in the rest of my script was causing it to fail. When I used just this block of code, the script executed properly. But, when it was in the rest of the script the windows still closed. Anyway, last question...is there a reason that when one of the two windows is active the rest of the code doesn't run? I thought that this was the purpose of the "Return".

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1: write this at the top of your script (before the first hotkey):

```
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetTitleMatchMode, Regex
```

2: Then you can use the not operator `!`:

```
if !(WinActive("ahk_class Notepad") or WinActive("ahk_class Calculator")) {
...
}
```

[Credit](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/73172-ifwinnotactive-ahk-class-xxx-or-ahk-class-yyy/page-2)